# Do I need to include http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.map in my appcache?

Tags: html5-appcache

During development, I was using

```
http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js
```

in both my html and my appcache.manifest.

When I went into production, I changed it to

```
http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js
```

in both places, but I saw this being referenced in the network tab in Google Chrome:

```
http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.map
```

Q: Do I need to include it as well?

I also saw these guys too:

```
http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/images/ajax-loader.gif
http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/images/icons-18-white.png
```

Are there any other things lurking in jQuery that might affect the application cache?

Answer (score 1):

Actually there are two ways to include jquery.

a) You directly put it on your server.
b) You load it from jquery site(currently you are doing this).

So when you are loading it from jquery site then it will be displayed in network tab.In fact it will improve performance.Jquery website itself take care of it that the javascript that they are providing should be minimized in size so that it will take less network bandwidth to load.

To increase performance  you should load it from CDN servers.They are best and fastest.

So there is no need to worry about it.

Answer (score 1):

The map files helps debugging. It helps the debugger to reverse the minification.
So you don't include it in the appcache.

For the second question:
Jquery mobile has not only a javascript file, but also css-files and images.
You need to include css and images also in the appcache (unless you don't use any of the icons)

Comment: might be worth to note that if you look in your debugging tool (eg. chrome dev tools or firebug) you will see an error because the `.min.map` cannot be loaded. But: it doesn't matter as the browser will only try to load it when your inspecting the javascript in the dev tools, NOT in normal operation. So that's pretty much the only 'error' you can ignore on a production server.